# Cannot read image from intranet, php export to word

Tags: php, html, ms-word

I want to export my page include my image to `Microsoft Word`,
But I have a problem, my image not shows in Microsoft word, but only show on the webpage.

**this is my code**

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/x-msword');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.doc" );
?>
     <!-- image from intranet -->
    <img src="http://192.168.100.97/i/xxx/header_surat_doc.jpg">

    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the `1500s` when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
```

But when I download file word 
this image not show

[image]

Help me. Thank's

Comment: How should word know what _h ttp://192.168.100.97_ is?

Comment: Use a library such as this one https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord to create your word documents

Comment: @B001ᛦ hmm word not know  192.168.100.97 ? not like a html can show my image ?